# Double free/corruption?

Tags: c, malloc, free

```
typedef struct {
    int *info;
} row;

struct {
    row* head;
    int len;
    int size;
} list;

int main{
    list.len = 0;
    list.size = 1;
    list.head = malloc(list.size * sizeof(row));
    //...... some other code that calls addRow (list.len) times
    for (i = list.len - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        free(list.head[i].info);/*****HERE**********/
    }
    free(list.head);
    }

void addRow(int* data) {
    int i;
    if (list.len == list.size) {
        row *temp = malloc(sizeof(row) * list.size * 2);
    if (temp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error (enter): (Line ##) Insufficient memory.\n");
        return;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < list.len; i++) {
        temp[i] = list.head[i];
    }
    free(list.head);
    list.head = temp;
    }
    list.head[list.len].info = malloc(sizeof(int) * numCols);
    for (i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
        list.head[list.len].info[i] = data[i];
    }
    list.len++;
```

}

This is the code that I used to addRow is were I malloc all the data. and I don't see why I'm getting a double free/ corruption error. At the area I marked HERE, I believe I am malloc-ing for all instances of info in the row struct, These line are the only ones doing malloc/free.

I just want to get into the habit  free-ing properly when terminating the program.

FULL PROGRAM:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

typedef struct {
    int *info;
} row;

struct {
    row* head;
    int len;
    int size;
} list;

static int sortCol, numCols;

int qSortCompare(const void*, const void*);
void printList();
int processInput();
void nullify(char*, int);

int main(int n, char **args) {
    sortCol = 1;
    numCols = 0;
    if (n > 1 && args[1][0] == '-' && args[1][1] == 'c') {
        sortCol = atoi(args[2]);
    }
    list.len = 0;
    list.size = 1;
    list.head = malloc(list.size * sizeof(row));
    processInput();
    if (sortCol < 1 || sortCol > numCols) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error (enter): (Line ##) Invalid column to sort.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printList();
    qsort(list.head, list.len, sizeof(row), &qSortCompare);
    printf("\n");
    printList();
    int i;
    printf("add1:%p\nadd2:%p\n", list.head[0].info, list.head[1].info);
    for (i = 0; i < list.len; i++) {
        free(list.head[i].info);
    }
    free(list.head);
    return 0;
}

void nullify(char* str, int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        str[i] = '\0';
}

int parseInt(char *str, int index) {
    int num = -1;
    sscanf(str + index, "%d", &num);
    return num;
}

void addRow(int* data) {
    int i;
    if (list.len == list.size) {
        row *temp = malloc(sizeof(row) * list.size * 2);
        if (temp == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error (enter): (Line ##) Insufficient memory.\n");
            return;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < list.len; i++) {
            temp[i] = list.head[i];
        }
        free(list.head);
        list.head = temp;
    }
    list.head[list.len].info = malloc(sizeof(int) * numCols);
    if (list.head[list.len].info == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error (enter): (Line ##) Insufficient memory.\n");
        return;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
        list.head[list.len].info[i] = data[i];
    }
    list.len++;
}

int processInput() {
    int i, maxChars = 200, totalN = 0;
    int *nums, curNumIndex = 0, onNum, curNum;
    numCols = maxChars / 2;
    nums = (int*) (malloc(sizeof(int) * numCols));
    char str[maxChars], ch;
    for (i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
        nums[i] = -1;
    }
    while (!feof(stdin)) {
        nullify(str, maxChars);
        fgets(str, maxChars, stdin);
        onNum = isdigit(str[0]);
        curNumIndex = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < maxChars; i++) {
            ch = str[i];
            if ((!isspace(ch)) && (!isdigit(ch)) && (ch != '\0')) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error 1: (Line ##) Invalid char in input.\n");
                //return 0;
            }
            if (isspace(ch) && onNum) {
                curNum = parseInt(str, curNumIndex);
                curNumIndex = i;
                nums[totalN % numCols] = curNum;
                totalN++;
                if (totalN % numCols == 0)
                    addRow(nums);
            } else {
                onNum = isdigit(str[i]);
            }
            if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\0')
                break;
        }
        if (numCols > totalN) {
            if (totalN > 0) {
                numCols = totalN;
                addRow(nums);
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr,
                        "Error (enter): (Line ##) Invalid first line of input.\n");
            }
        }
        if (ch != '\n' && ch != '\0') {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "Error (enter): (Line ##) A row from input too long.\n");
            //return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

int qSortCompare(const void *c1, const void *c2) {
    row *t1, *t2;
    t1 = (row*)c1;
    t2 = (row*)c2;
    return t1->info[sortCol - 1] - t2->info[sortCol - 1];
}

void printList() {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < list.len; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
            printf("%10d   ", list.head[i].info[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Program needs a EOF terminated input of integer numbers. Specifically with the same number of integers before the newline.

UPDATE: I used gdb to analysis the free part i it only fails on the second iteration, using `for(i = 0; i < list.len; i++)` and `for(i = list.len - 1; i > 0 ; i--)`

Comment: Is it me or are you trying to change class members without initializing an object from the class? O.o instead of `list.len = 0` you should try `list l; l.len = 0;` :) and change the rest of the code, so it does use a variable instead of a class name.

Comment: @TheOneAndOnly its you. `list` already *is* a variable; not a type.

Comment: This code won't even *compile*. `main()` isn't declared properly, `i` is undefined in `main()`, `numCols` is undefined in `addRows`. **Post Real Code**

Comment: @WhozCraig I left out most of my code, the entire file would we at least twice as long as this. If this isn't sufficient i could post it all...

Comment: @Whoz Posted the full

Comment: I don't think it's related to the double-free error, but you're never updating `list.size` when you grow the array. BTW, don't you know about `realloc()`?

Comment: @Barmar I've heard of it, but all heard hearsay that it is better to malloc , check if NULL, the then assigned.

Comment: That's BS. `realloc` is just like what you're doing: `malloc`, copy all the elements, then free the original. But since it's part of the implementation, it can do clever things, like extend the allocation if there's available space, instead of copying.

Comment: @SGM1 In case you needed to care about yet-another-thing, your free-loop is *not* freeing the *first* entry in your list. you loop so long as `i > 0`, but the first entry, the one at `list.head[0]`, it not reached with that loop, so you can add a memory *leak* to your woes. =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another thing is that I don't see the update to list.size (it should be updated when resizing head)

Comment: Sorry, but i forgot to add the -1 on the short version, i had that in my current code and the full version.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't seem to be it. I'm getting a double free/ corruption on the second iteration of the free-loop.

Comment: actually i was wrong list.len == list.size is fine but still not sure where list.size updated

Comment: That was it Thank you, ad that in to you answer and I'll accept it. PS  why can't I \@ Benoit you?

Comment: Updated the answer and I'm not sure why about the @Benoit

Answer (score 1):

***"I just want to get into the habit free-ing properly when terminating the program."***

The correct way to handle things like this is to free a non-NULL pointer and then set the pointer to NULL.

#### For example:

```
int* x = malloc (sizeof (int));

if (x != NULL) {
  free (x);
  x = NULL;
}

/* Misc. Code ... */

/* Now for whatever reason, you want to free x again */

/* This branch is never triggered, because you were smart enough to set x to NULL
 *  when you freed it the first time...
 */
if (x != NULL) {
  free (x);
  x = NULL;
}
```

Comment: While an interesting habit, `free()` is perfectly happy with a NULL pointer. *Indeterminate* pointers and allocation *overruns* are almost always the culprit of undefined behavior when it comes to `malloc()` usage. Invoking `free()` on a null pointer will not trip your program up (and yes, sadly that is often undesirable).

Comment: This approach doesn't help if you store the pointer in multiple variables. Setting one of them to NULL doesn't clear the others.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yes, but the pointer does not become NULL simply by calling `free (...)`. You have to set it to NULL, which is what half of the free guard does.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman My point is the *test* for NULL is not doing any special favors besides avoiding a pointer-save at the cost of a pointer-eval. Just invoke `free()` and set the pointer to NULL.

Comment: @Barmar: However, in this case when he frees `list.head`, if he had set it to NULL this issue would not arise. Because he would not be trying to free the elements of `list.head [...]` which were already freed. Technically he should set `list.len` to 0 and `list.head` to NULL.

Comment: Okay, but I check NULL for ever malloc I've made and and primary in free-ing right before terminating the program. The setting to NULL is good practice, I understand, but this program using malloc only in these 2 functions and one when parsing input to store it (but this pointer doe not get assigned anywhere else.

Comment: @SGM1 if there is a chance a pointer can be used again, setting to NULL after a `free()` isn't just good-practice. its mandatory. The place to *check* for NULL is after the malloc and before usage. The place to *set* NULL is after the free OR when transferring ownership.

Comment: @WhozCraig: The reason I used the test for NULL before freeing is because usually when you free memory like this you do more than simply free the pointer. You might do clean-up, etc. For instance, if he decides to free a list, he will probably run through starting at the head element and freeing all of the linked nodes. If he did not test for head == NULL before starting this, then this sort of thing happens.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman that would be the "check for NULL is after the malloc **and before usage**" portion of my prior comment. Checking for NULL simply to do a `free()`is fruitless. But setting NULL *after* a `free` is *always* a good practice, to be sure.